# Send keys to HTML element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am writing an automation script for sports betting in Python using Selenium. I am stuck at a point where Selenium is unable to click or send keys to the specific HTML element highlighted in the following screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbljY.png).

Here is what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.bet365.com")
### Some code here to navigate to a particular match
driver.switch_to.frame(bet_driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("bs-Stake")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("100")
```

This returns the following error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div class="bs-Stake"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

If I try instead

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("stk bs-Stake_TextBox")
```

I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .stk bs-Stake_TextBox
```

I would appreciate help navigating to the HTML element, clicking and sending keys to it, using any method available in Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `sendkeys`  with `webdriver wait` so element would be able to interact.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((CSS_SELECTOR, ".stk.bs-Stake_TextBox")))
element.send_keys("100")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked (changed CSS_SELECTOR to "css selector"). Can you briefly explain what the code is doing and why this works?

Comment: @AfBM  as explicit wait is standard practice so I utilized wait for element’d visibility. First it will check is element visible and then it will send keys to element.

Comment: Another issue  I have observed is, the class name you are using have space so it will not works and throws compoundClassException. That is why I have preferred to use CSS. In css space is replaced with ‘.’

Answer (score 0):

Although CSS styles are inherited... the class designations are not. Your css selector has three separate classes in it, but your element sample only has one.

Selenium is designed to mimic the same actions that a person can perform... the error suggests that the field is not available for interaction.... find out why.